# Viewport shading in Blender 2.8 (want to select vertices like old method)

Tags: 3d-view, selection-tools, experimental-features

[image]

I want to be able to select back faces/vertices of an object like in the older versions of Blender.

The issue is that I cannot switch between view modes like we were able to in the older versions using Shift-z, z, etc.  This is preventing me from b-selecting vertices since they are hidden behind a solid.

In the other versions I could swap between solid and wire-frame with a shortcut key and did not have to switch into Blender Internal to get a wire-frame.

So in the example above, how can I change the viewport render mode to allow selection through the rest of the object?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it about an incomplete development version

Comment: you could switch over to blender render and press z, and when you're done go back to EEVEE

Comment: What about the little "Limit selection to visible" button at the bottom panel of the 3D viewport in Edit mode? That lets you select through the mesh without going into wireframe view